# How to fill the array in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

Is there any other better way to fill up the array like :

```
var arr = [];
var i = 0;
$('select').children('option').each( function() {
    arr[i++] = $(this).html();
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var arr = $("select > option").map(function() {
    return this.innerHTML;
}).get();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/UZzd5/

Answer (score 11):

using `push()` :

```
var arr = [];
$('select').children('option').each( function() {
   arr.push($(this).html());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [];
$('select option').html(function(i, html) {
    arr.push(html);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QStkd/349/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.fill = function(value, length){
    while(length--){
        this[length] = value;
    }
    return this;
}

// example:
var coords = [].fill(0, 3);
```